# Overlay textLabel and UIImageView in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiimageview, uiimage

I have a problem positioning a textLabel and detailTextLabel into a custom UITableViewCell that has a UIImageView appearing behind the textLabel and detailTextLabel.

Refer to the image - it will make more sense 
--> what you're looking a UITableView, where each bubble represents a different UITableViewCell.

[image]

Essentially, I am trying to fit the textLabel and detailTextLabel into the bubble you see by expanding the bubble dimensions.  However, no matter what I try the bubble will not change it's width and height even if I change the UIImageView frame or bounds or contentMode.

Here is the relevant code in cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
//Set font and style        
cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
cell.detailTextLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];    

// Assign our own background image for the cell
UIImage *cellBackgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Chat.png"];

UIImageView *cellBackgroundImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:cellBackgroundImage];
//[cellBackgroundImageView setBounds:CGRectMake(0, 0, 20, 20)];
//[cellBackgroundImageView setImage:cellBackgroundImage];

//cellBackgroundImageView.frame = CGRectMake(cellBackgroundImageView.frame.origin.x,         cellBackgroundImageView.frame.origin.y, 20, 20);
//cellBackgroundImageView.bounds = CGRectMake(cellBackgroundImageView.frame.origin.x, cellBackgroundImageView.frame.origin.y, 0, 0);
cellBackgroundImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;

cellBackgroundImageView.image = cellBackgroundImage;
cell.backgroundView = cellBackgroundImageView;
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Don't do it here, I did it by writing frame of image and label in LayoutSubviews method in custom cell class.

Just 
-(void)layoutSubviews
{ setframe: for both UI components }

Answer (score 0):

Dont use Aspect FIll, use either scaleToFill, or set image to image view using imageCapInsets .

```
- (UIImage *)resizableImageWithCapInsets:(UIEdgeInsets)capInsets resizingMode:(UIImageResizingMode)resizingMode
```

For your Image, it must be like

```
UIImage *cellBackgroundImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"Chat.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(20, 70, 40, 20) resizingMode:UIImageResizingModeStretch]
```

Comment: placing UIImage *cellBackgroundImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"Chat.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(20, 70, 40, 20) resizingMode:UIImageResizingModeStretch] into cellForRowAtIndexPath does not resize the bubble to enclose the text.

Comment: instead of setting cell.backGroundView, try adding cellBackgroundImage as subView to cell.contentView.And set frame of cellBackgroundImage UIImageView such that it encloses both textLabel and detailTextLabel.And cap insets make sure that your bubble image looks fine after stretching.